# Showing that a function space is Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $D = (0,T) \times (0,\infty)$ and suppose $V := \bigg\{ f \in C(D) \bigg| \|f \|_V := \sup_{t,s}\bigg|\frac{f(t,s)}{1+s^2} \bigg| < \infty\bigg\}$, where $C(D) = \bigl\{f : D \to \mathbb{R} \big|\textrm{ f is continuous component-wise}\bigr\}$. I want to show that $V$ alongwith the norm $\| \cdot\|_V$ forms a Banach space.

I started by considering $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, a Cauchy sequence in $V$, and now I should ideally have a candidate function to which the Cauchy sequence will converge. How do I explicitly construct such a candidate function? I am new to functional analysis, so references would also be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(f_n)$ is Cauchy and $\epsilon >0$ then there exists $n_0$ such that $|f_n(t,s)-f_m(t,s)| <\epsilon (1+s^{2})$ for all $n,m \geq n_0$. For any fixed $t$ amd $s$ this implies that $(f_n(t,s))$ is Cauchy. Define $f(t,s)$ as $\lim f_n(t,s)$. I will let you handle the rest.

Comment: Thank you! I proceeded as you explained and here I am- $$ \begin{aligned}
        \|f\|_V = \sup_{t,s} \bigg|\frac{f(t,s)}{1+s^2} \bigg| &=\sup_{t,s} \bigg|\frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(t,s)}{1+s^2}\bigg| \\
        &\leq \sup_{t,s} \bigg|\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{t,s} \frac{f_n(t,s)}{1+s^2}\bigg|\\
        &= \sup_{t,s}\big|\lim_{n \to \infty} \|f_n\|_V\big| \\&= \big|\lim_{n \to \infty} \|f_n\|_V\big| 
    \end{aligned}$$. How do I show that the RHS $< \infty$?

Comment: Cauchy sequences are always bounded in the norm @P.J.

Comment: Thank you so much.